# Get uRapidFlow logs for an import profile batch

Tags: magento, import

I am running a php script using a cron job to run a uRapidFlow / RapidFlow import profile. [Here](http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/run_scheduled) is the documented code I found to help me do this.

I need to be able to run through the imported batch, row by row, and do some processing based on if the row was imported successfully or not. It would also be very convenient and useful to be able to send email notifications on failed imports in general as well. If anyone has any idea, or can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful. I don't see any documentation for this online, so I am going through the module code and database trying to figure it out myself.

I am using Magento EE 1.12.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The best bet, unless you modify the uRapidFlow extension (check license information before doing so). Would be to extend it and use a observed event.

Try the observer :  catalog_product_import_finish_before    Which is triggered after each product is imported.  Bare in mind this solution would be triggered globably for any manual imports, so if you build a small extension, perhaps make it easy to toggle on and off.

More can be found on Magento's observers here : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Note as you've not specified which version of Magento you are using, you'll have to check if that observer is supported in your version.

Comment: The `catalog_product_import_finish_before` event is a core event thrown by the ImportExport module, something which I don't believe uRapidFlow will trigger. Since uRapidFlow is encoded with IonCube it also won't be that easy to extend and add in any hook points, there are some events fired by the module, not sure if they'll be usefull (http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/customization). It should be possible to pull back basic information from the Profile model (see it's $_saveFields).